# Angular 7 ngx chips working functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, ngx-chips

i have a scenario where i want to get input from the field and bind the content of input to tags in another span.
I'm trying this with ngx chips in angular 7 project for a form.I want a div/span with those inputed values above the Reactive form[image]

Here is the picture of form
i have imported

```
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
```

How can i achieve this?(Basically i don't want to input tags inside the same input field rather on another span)

Comment: Can you create stackblitz demo for this

Comment: Hi HKI345! Could you please provide a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ so that we can help you reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Justcode I have added git repository of my application example.i want this questions scenario to be implemented only on feedback form https://github.com/HusnaKhanam/MyApplication.git